# Tikz positioning of rectangles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone tell me, why in the following example, the edges of the rectangle don't touch and what I can do about it?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor} {cmyk}{0.6262,0.5157,0.4597,0.3977}

\newlength{\lema}
\setlength{\lema}{0.14\paperwidth}
\newlength{\toma}
\setlength{\toma}{0.2\paperheight}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight-\toma) rectangle (-0.5\paperwidth+\lema,-0.5\paperheight);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-0.5\paperwidth+\lema,0.5\paperheight) rectangle (0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight-\toma);
\end{tikzpicture}
}   
}   
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage

\phantom{wbweb}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

My output:
[image]

Comment: Try to put an comment sign `%` at the end of the first tikzpicture. The line feed is interpreted as a space in LaTeX and is rendered as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired result, this should be the easiest solution:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor} {cmyk}{0.6262,0.5157,0.4597,0.3977}

\newlength{\lema}
\setlength{\lema}{0.14\paperwidth}
\newlength{\toma}
\setlength{\toma}{0.2\paperheight}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [fill=titlepagecolor] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (\lema,-\toma)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [fill=titlepagecolor] (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (\lema,-\toma)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage

\phantom{wbweb}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stefan's code made a little bit simpler with `even odd rule`

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor} {cmyk}{0.6262,0.5157,0.4597,0.3977}

\newlength{\lema}
\setlength{\lema}{0.14\paperwidth}
\newlength{\toma}
\setlength{\toma}{0.2\paperheight}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill [fill=titlepagecolor, even odd rule] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (\lema,-\toma)$)  
(current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (\lema,-\toma)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage

\phantom{wbweb}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]